# Is there a javascript method that returns the state of a given Audio object?

Tags: javascript, audio, methods

I'm writing a simple puzzle game in javascript.  [You can play it here](http://jeremyseanbell.com/games/) and the [source code is here](http://jeremyseanbell.com/games/12tone.js).  It uses musical notes as its game pieces, and you can press a "Play" button to make it play the notes.  The notes also light up when they are being played.  The problem is that there seems to be a lag between the sound and the changing graphics.

For the audio playback method,`this.playToneRow()`, I used a global variable to iterate through all the notes, and then in the method that shows the pieces, `this.drawNotes()`, I just grabbed the value of that global variable to determine which game piece should light up.  But I'm guessing this isn't the best way to do it, because there seems to be a delay between the .play() call and the actual sound.

So I was thinking that a better way to control the changing graphics would be some kind of method that tells which audio object is currently playing (if any) and then I can just change the corresponding image.

```
this.playToneRow = function()
{
    var x = 0,
        length = (this.notes.length + 2),
        myArray = this.notes;
    j = 0;
    currentSound = this.player;

    function runIteration () {
        x = myArray[j];

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            if (typeof x === 'number')
            {
                noteSound[x].play();
            }
        }, 500);

        if (j === length)
        {
            j = -1;
            currentSound = 0;
            return;
        }

        j++;

        setTimeout(runIteration, 500);
    }

    runIteration();

};

this.drawNotes = function()
{
    this.noteText = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        this.noteText += noteNames[this.notes[i]];
        this.noteText += ", ";
        if (((j - 3)  === i) && (currentSound === this.player))
        {
            ctx.drawImage(this.gamePieceHi, (i * 52) + 85, 275 - (this.notes[i] * 17.7));
        }
        else
        {
            ctx.drawImage(this.gamePiece, (i * 52) + 95, 285 - (this.notes[i] * 17.7));
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question (not the full code, just the parts you reference).

Comment: [HTMLMediaElement.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `this.playToneRow()` is queuing a sound for 500ms from now via `setTimeout()`, but the part that draws the note is running immediately.

Comment: The easy fix is to just delay each affected draw. If you want to do it right though, it would probably be better to have an update function that handles both video and audio. It could queue a *single*, non-recursive requestAnimationFrame() for the video (even though the draw is probably not that heavy and you're not targeting constant maximum FPS) and play() for the audio, then sleep until the next note (if one exists).

Comment: Thank you for your replies, Jared and Scott. I made some changes to my code so now it sort of works, though I'm sure there's a better way to do it. I should mention that this is all pretty new to me, and I don't totally know what I'm doing! Anyway, I included my updated code above. I changed the playToneRow() method so that it does 2 iterations past the end of the array, and then I added the `if (typeof x === 'number')` condition so it won't try to access past the end of the array. Then in `drawNotes()` I subtract 3 from the global `j`. That seems to work, though I'm not totally clear why!